# Add points to Path in Canvas Dynamically

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-canvas

I am new to Android, I was learning how to draw on canvas. How can I add new points to Path and draw them dynamically? 
Right Now I call a function (setPoints()) of my custom view class from MainActivity and pass the points to it but the path is not being drawn. Can someone please suggest the right way or help me with this? I am stuck at this.

```
public class RenderPointsMap extends View {

public int width;
public int height;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Path mPath;
Context context;
private Paint mPaint;
private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOLERANCE = 5;
Vector<PointF> temp = new Vector<>();
 PointF usethis  = new PointF();


public RenderPointsMap(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(c, attrs);
    context = c;

    // we set a new Path
    mPath = new Path();

    // and we set a new Paint with the desired attributes
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2f);


}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    // your Canvas will draw onto the defined Bitmap
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
}

// override onDraw
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    // draw the mPath with the mPaint on the canvas when onDraw
    mCanvas = canvas;
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}

public void setPoints(Vector<PointF> points){
    mPath.moveTo(200, 200);
    for(int i=1;i<points.size();i++)
        mPath.lineTo(points.get(i).x, points.get(i).y);

    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Points are set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Comment: You need to call `invalidate()` after the loop in your `setPoints()` method. I would also mention that the loop you have in the constructor is modifying and adding the same `Point` object repeatedly, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @MikeM. do I have to call invalidate() after every iteration in for loop of setPoints) or only at the end? I want all lines to be shown. (In the constructor I was using that for debugging, edited the code and removed that from the constructor) Thanks

Comment: At the end, after the loop. The whole `Path` will be drawn at once in `onDraw()`, so there's no need to trigger a redraw after each segment.

Comment: remove variable mCanvas, it is working on onDraw only.